# How to reset the timeout counter of a HTTPSession?

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

Is there a way to reset the timeout counter of a `HTTPSession` other than through serving a HTTP request?

I'm looking for something like

```
session.resetTimeout();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you've a `HttpSession` at hands without having a concrete `HttpServletRequest`?

You *could* increment the [max inactive interval](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29) with the sum of the [current inactive time](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getLastAccessedTime%28%29) and the [max inactive interval](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval%28%29).

```
int maxInactiveInterval = session.getMaxInactiveInterval();
int currentInactiveTime = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - session.getLastAccessedTime() / 1000);
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(maxInactiveInterval + currentInactiveTime);
```

However, this requires some [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlet-filters) which resets it back to the default max inactive interval again on every request when its value is off from the default.

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(defaultMaxInactiveInterval);
```

On Servlet 3.0, this value is obtainable by [`SessionCookieConfig#getMaxAge()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig.html#getMaxAge%28%29).

```
int defaultMaxInactiveInterval = getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().getMaxAge();
```